# Video FPS, in and out

Tags: ffmpeg

Task: make video ten times quicker.
Solution algorithm: take every 10th frame from source and put it to out, setting out fps as original.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" out.mp4
```

This works on source. I've got every 10th frame from source video.

But I cannot produce out video.

I make many combinations of switches. In some conditions output video has original fps, but 10 frames are similar, so when playing - frames switches 3 times in a second.
In some conditions I've got file with real fps=3.
I try -r option for input file, -r option for output file, filter "fps=30", -framerate and so on.

Again: I want to take every 10th frame from input (original fps is 30), send it as single frame to output and set output fps to 30, so I get output video 10 times shorter than input and 10 times faster in playback.

When I've got 3 fps video, I think: this is it. Now I should change fps in this video from 3 to 30 - and all done.
But I cannot do this.

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vcodec copy -r 30 out2.mp4
```

I've got again 3-fps video.

Audio synchronizing, of course, is not applicable in this situation.

Comment: If you have solved your problem the post an answer in the answer section below. You will be able to mark your question as "answered" after a couple of days.

Comment: This filter doesn't decrease frames number. Use https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Answer (score 0):

Decimate timestamps and then select every 10th frame.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/10,select=not(mod(n\,10))" out.mp4
```

Audio is ignored.